# Why WPF Application throwing 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Infrastructure.StartException' after installation?

Tags: c#, wpf, signalr

I am developing a chat application in WPF using SignalR .There are two projects in it, namely:-

1)WPF Client

2)WPF Server

I've set multiple project on running(Server and Client).It is running fine locally ,but when I install my Server and client project, the Server project don't let any client to connect to it. It throws Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Infrastructure.StartException.

And when i Run my Server project locally and then try connecting the Installed Client Application. it gets connected and works fine then onwards.

I m not getting the actual reason behind this exception. Googled for it but didn't get any solution.

This is the line of code where I get the exception.

```
    await Connection.Start();
```

Details of exception are as follows:-

```
    StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1,          Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:{ Date: Tue, 19 Jul 2016 2:36:32 GMT Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0 Content-Length: 0 }
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This looks like an administrative issue. Since you're self-hosting SignalR, you at least have to allow your application to use URL you provided via `hetsh add urlacl`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc307223(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have checked the "Run as administrator" option of my server application. But still it doesn't allow clients to connect.

Comment: "Run as admin" has nothing to do with HTTP.SYS. You have to configure URL ACL using command from above.